# multiselect choice alert dialog only changes value of last item on clicking an item android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I have a multichoice alert dialog which displays an arraylist properly in a list with checkbox in each row.I want to change the value of the checked item in the list ie...if it is checked it should be 1 else 0.The problem is on clicking it only fetches the last item in the list and changes its value

```
 alertdialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FormBuilderActivity.this);

    final boolean[] Selectedtruefalse = new boolean[multiSelectPopulationList[0].size()];

    for(int x=0;x<multiSelectPopulationList[0].size();x++)
    {
        if(multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(x).getValue()==0)
        {
            Selectedtruefalse[x]=false;
        }
        else
        {
            Selectedtruefalse[x]=true;
        }
    }

    final ArrayList<MultiSelectModel> ItemsIntoList;

    ItemsIntoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ItemsIntoList.clear();
    ItemsIntoList.addAll(multiSelectPopulationList[0]);

    final String[] AlertDialogItems = new String[multiSelectPopulationList[0].size()];
    for(int z=0;z<multiSelectPopulationList[0].size();z++)
    {
        AlertDialogItems[z]=multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(z).getPopulationListItem();
    }

    alertdialogbuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(AlertDialogItems, Selectedtruefalse, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if(multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getValue()==0)
            {
                multiSelectModel.setValue(1);
                multiSelectPopulationList[0].set(which, multiSelectModel);
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]rowlabel",multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getName());
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]rowId",multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getRowId());
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]optionValue",multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getPopulationListItem());
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]checkValue",String.valueOf(multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getValue()));

            }
            else
            {
                multiSelectModel.setValue(1);
                multiSelectPopulationList[0].set(which, multiSelectModel);
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]rowlabel",multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getName());
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]rowId",multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getRowId());
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]optionValue",multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getPopulationListItem());
                Log.d("Multisel["+which+"]checkValue",String.valueOf(multiSelectPopulationList[0].get(which).getValue()));
            }



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried custom multiselect pop up dialog with search option.

Create class name with **MultiSelect.java**

```
public class MultiSelect {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

create xml file with name **pop_up_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxt_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk_select_all"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select All"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_recycle_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter_select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge_orange"
        android:text="Select"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

create Adapter Class with name **PrefStateAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import <your_project_package>.R;
import <your_project_package>.MultiSelect;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PrefStateAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private List<MultiSelect> listState;
    private List<MultiSelect> tempStateList;
    private CityFilter cityFilter;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public PrefStateAdapter(Context context, List<MultiSelect> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listState = list;
        this.tempStateList = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listState.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_pref_city, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pref_city_name);
            holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_pref_city);
            holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    MultiSelect m = listState.get((Integer) buttonView.getTag());
                    m.setSelected(isChecked);

                    for (int i = 0; i < tempStateList.size(); i++) {
                        MultiSelect multiSelect = tempStateList.get(i);
                        if (m.getId() == multiSelect.getId()) {
                            multiSelect.setSelected(isChecked);
                        }
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        MultiSelect m = listState.get((Integer) holder.mCheckBox.getTag());
        holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.mTextView.setText(m.getName());


        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(m.isSelected());

        //holder.mCheckBox.setChecked((boolean) holder.mCheckBox.getTag(m.getId()));


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (cityFilter == null) {
            cityFilter = new CityFilter();
        }
        return cityFilter;
    }

    class CityFilter extends Filter {


        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                List<MultiSelect> filterList = new ArrayList<MultiSelect>();
                for (int i = 0; i < tempStateList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((tempStateList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        MultiSelect multiSelect = new MultiSelect();
                        multiSelect.setName(tempStateList.get(i).getName());
                        multiSelect.setId(tempStateList.get(i).getId());
                        multiSelect.setSelected(tempStateList.get(i).isSelected());
                        filterList.add(multiSelect);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = tempStateList.size();
                results.values = tempStateList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            listState = (List<MultiSelect>) results.values;
            //tempCityList = (List<MultiSelect>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;
    }
}
```

finally method that will show multiselect pop up

```
private void showDesignationPopUp(final List<MultiSelect> list) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourClassName.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(YourClassName.this);
    //dialog.setCancelable(false);
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_list, null);

    final ListView cityList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
    final EditText etxtSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etxt_search);
    final Button btnFilteSelect = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_filter_select);

    //If you don't want to use search option, comment below line
    etxtSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final PrefStateAdapter adapter = new PrefStateAdapter(CandiPrefJobLocationNew.this, list);

    cityList.setAdapter(adapter);

    etxtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    btnFilteSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //you can get selected item in this
        }
    });

    dialog.setView(v);

    ad2 = dialog.show();
}
```

This is working code, you need to change in drawable in xml file
I hope this will help you
Happy coding!!!!
All the best!!

Comment: I have not tried the complete code but your one line solved my problem ie...   MultiSelect multiSelect = tempStateList.get(i).Thanks

Comment: can u also tell me how to set the item with value 1 to checked in my code only when I open the alertdialog?

Comment: I am not getting your problem

Comment: when I open the alertdialog I want to  the item in list with value 1 as checked but I cannot find out the checkbox view in my code.can u tell me where do I set the item with value 1 as checked in my code?

Comment: I am not understanding your code. See  this link if it find useful https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-alertdialog-multichoice.html

Comment: I have used the same tutorial.The only problem is that when I open the alert dialog I want to display some items as checked by default if its value in arraylist is 1.So i need to get the view of the checkBox which I dont know how to.so please help me